# How to define an append-only table in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database

I am not able to find a way to create a table which only allows append-only. I want to know if this is possible in MySQL or not.

Comment: Append-only table means?

Answer (score 4):

I thing it is not possible in that sense. What do thing about grant and revoke. You could only grant users to insert rows.

GRANT INSERT ON table1 TO 'user@skldfj.de';

Comment: Yeah, that will effectively make the table append-only. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ARCHIVE engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/archive-storage-engine.html), which allows INSERT, SELECT but not UPDATE or DELETE.

But the archive engine does not support any indexes—literally every read forces a table scan—so you might be better off using a traditional storage engine and enforcing insert-only either in your application logic or in your grants (like michaeldbjava suggests).